# Wordpress How to make a section dynamic in custom theme in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

Want to make the below section dynamic in wordpress custom theme

[View the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx4z4.png)

1. The Data of the section will be map with the blog post/ a custom field to upload from wordpress admin panel. (like a blog post).
2. want to be able to select the post map with .

Comment: _"Is there any plugin or tutorial avlable"_ - this here is not the right place to ask that, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Answer (score 0):

you try https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/
wp_customize function use for your static front page or you can use widget system for that.